# text/string encoder in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC in my project. I have used Html.Encode to display some text content and while editing i am finding the text and displaying it in the edit textbox.

Here is my issue, if the text contains some special character, say , while editing its displayed as `&lt;hello&gt;` but i wanna display the same as

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Html.Decode it before displaying it to user.

Javascript does not decode html natively

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.PropertyName) %>

<textarea>
<%= your_variable %>
</textarea>
```

same can be done  for input.type=text

**OR**

whatever the way u r doing, there is no need to do Html.Encode when displaying ur data in text box/textarea. Html.Encoding is basically done to avoid injecting script that malicious user tries to inject into ur page. But there is no such issue in case of textarea/input.type=text

Comment: if i use <% =Model.PropertyName%>, its not displaying the data which contains special character...like <Hello>

Comment: remember when u want to display data to div, like inside a div, you have to do Html.Encode. while when you want to display data inside textarea/input.type=text. Just skip the part Html.Encode, i think that would run ur code smoothly.

Comment: I am displaying the content in a span using Html.Encode, but when i get the same and display it in the textbox using javascript i am getting &lt;hello&gt;

Comment: oh!!, so are are you first showing text inside span and then using javascript to show that text inside a textbox??

Comment: then before placing you html into textbox, with javascript you have to encode it, read this; http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

Answer (score 0):

The Html.Encode() doesn't support an option to prevent double encoding HTML entities like the PHP htmlentities() function. You'd need to either decode the string first or write a custom HTML Helper that doesn't double encode characters.